# Why is my array comparison algorithm giving me the wrong output?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, algorithm, comparison

So I'm trying to complete the Hackerrank.com challenge "[Compare The Triplets](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/compare-the-triplets/problem)", and I got an unexpected output:

```
Input (stdin)
    5 6 7
    3 6 10
Your Output (stdout)
    0 1
Expected Output
    1 1
```

So I already have code that works for what the challenge wants me to do, compare an array with three elements, but I figured that one that will take an array with n number of elements and compare them would be more useful. I wrote some code to try and get this to work, but the output is not what it should be.  The goal is to compare the values of the elements in two separate arrays.  Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

# Complete the compareTriplets function below.
def compareTriplets(a, b):
loopLen = 0
if len(a) > len(b):
    loopLen = len(a)
elif len(a) == len(b):
    loopLen = len(a)
elif len(a) < len(b):
    loopLen = len(b)
for i in range(0, loopLen):
    bob = 0
    alice = 0
    if a[i] > b[i]:
        bob += 1
    elif a[i] == b[i]:
        bob += 0
        alice += 0
    elif a[i] < b[i]:
        alice += 1
    i += 1

return bob, alice

if __name__ == '__main__':
fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

a = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

b = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

result = compareTriplets(a, b)

fptr.write(' '.join(map(str, result)))
fptr.write('\n')

fptr.close()
```

***EDIT: Question answered in comments***

Comment: You set `i = 0` in the loop (which is wrong) and increment `i += 1` at the end of it (which is useless).

Comment: @MichaelButscher I removed it and the same error occurs

Comment: are you referring to `lists` as `arrays`?

Comment: And what is the error or output (edit the questions to show it as properly formatted text)?

Comment: You should remove your working code and instead give us the input and expected ouput

Comment: @vash_the_stampede yes

Comment: @Jodast read above comment, give us input and expected output if you want to find a better way, all we have is your solution with no desired outcome nor input

Comment: @MichaelButscher added i/o

Comment: Resetting `alice` and `bob` to `0` for each loop iteration is wrong.

Comment: Ohhh, I didn't realize it was resetting them!  It works when I remove the alice = 0 bob =  0 from the loop!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can zip the lists and evaluate from there, this will work for any size list now

```
alice = [5, 6, 7]
bob = [3, 6, 10]

score = [0,0]

l = list(zip(alice, bob))

for i in l:
    if i[0] > i[1]:
        score[0] += 1
    elif i[1] > i[0]:
        score[1] += 1
    else:  
        pass

print(score)
```

> ```
> [1, 1]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the function below would work for any number of elements within the 2 lists

```
def compTrip(a,b):
    alice = 0
    bob = 0
    result = []
    for i, j in zip(a,b):
        if i < j:
            alice = alice + 1
        if j < i:
            bob = bob + 1
    result.append(bob)
    result.append(alice)        
    return(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

@Jodast - the error in your code is that you're reinitializing the variables `alice` and `bob` to 0 on every iteration of the for loop. Remove that out of the for loop and your code will work like a charm.

Lines with error (remove these lines out of for loop):

```
bob = 0
alice = 0
```

Happy Coding! :)